# is there a better way to do this?(if the the in put was 1 and 1000000 its taking for ever to do this)

Tags: java

Given two integers N and M (N ≤ M), output all the prime numbers between N and M inclusive, one per line.

N and M will be positive integers less than or equal to 1,000,000,000.
   The difference between N and M will be less than or equal to 5,000,000.

Sample Input

5 20

Sample Output

5
  7
  11
  13
  17
  19

```
import java.util.*;

public class primes2 {
    public static void main (String[] args){

        Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);
        long num1,num2,i;

        num1=scan.nextInt();
        num2=scan.nextInt();


          for (i=num1; i < num2; i++ )
          {       
          long j;

          for (j=2; j<i; j++)
          {
          long n = i%j;
            if (n==0){
                break;
            }
          }
          if(i == j)
          {
          System.out.println(i);
          }

      }

    }

}
```

Comment: yes im done my work but its to slow to get the out put 1 and 1000000

Comment: the second for could go only to Math.sqrt(i)

Comment: can u give me an example

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/8904563/1011995 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/8887316/1011995

Comment: [Codereview.SE](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) is a better fit for "Is there a better way?"-type questions. Note there's already a question on [generating primes in a range](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/5996/), though it's for C++ rather than java (which is appropriate for a homework problem).

Answer (score 5):

Yes, there is a better way to do it: the [sieve of Eratosthenes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes?banner=no) with two arrays:

1. first array from `2` to `sqrt(M)`;
2. second array from `N` to `M`.

Comment: +1 for answer, wish I could give extra +1 for workarounding the wikipedia blocking issue without using google cache.

Answer (score 0):

You have to do the exact opposite: instead of checking number by number to see if it's prime, take the first prime you know and then select OUT every number that is a multiple of it. Then get the next prime number and do it again. This is called sieve of Eratosthenes, the code is simple, but do it yourself!

Answer (score 0):

You can check this out as well:

http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Efficient_Prime_Number_Generating_Algorithms

By the way, it took me 30 seconds to find it...

Comment: but it has to be less than 5 s